# Ant if statement

Tags: ant

Below is a snippet from my `build.xml` file.
I want to modify the file so that the jar name is set depending on the value of a variable within the build file.

```
<info 
   jarName="java get"
   jarUrl="${deploy-url}${polish.jarName}"
/>
```

So something like -

```
<info
   if(${deploy-url} == "test")
      jarName="java get" 
   else
      jarName="java test" 
      jarUrl="${deploy-url}${polish.jarName}"
/>
```

Or can I call a java program to return the jar name, so something like -

```
<info
   jarName=java programToExecute 
   jarUrl="${deploy-url}${polish.jarName}"
/>
```

Thanks for any suggestions,

Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Ant Contrib project](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) has a selection of [custom tasks](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html), including an [`<if>` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) that will let you do this. It's clumsy, but it works.

Comment: I tried the following but it's throwning and error, am I using it correctly ?     <if>
     <equals arg1="${foo}" arg2="bar" />
     <then>
     jarName="${polish.vendor}-${polish.name}-${polish.locale}-FAMA.jar" 
     </then>
     <else>
     jarName="${polish.vendor}-${polish.name}-${polish.locale}-FAMA.jar" 
     </else>
    </if>

Comment: @user470184: Edit your question, or start a new one, rather than putting such things in as comments.